# Get HTTP Status from InternetExplorer Com Object

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, automation, http-status-codes

I am struggling to get Status of page that I am trying to get using IneternetExplorer COM objects method Navigate.

I found that there is event NavigateError and have saw some overrides examples for VBS (http://www.visualbasicscript.com/VBS-Connect-to-website-to-check-active-m68559.aspx) and for Perl (http://www.codegithub.com/watch?v=0iiJyUPXQeqW) but how to override this method in IE???

Here sample code :

```
    $ie = New-Object -comobject InternetExplorer.Application
    $ie.visible = $true
    $ie.Navigate($URL)
    while( $ie.busy){Start-Sleep 1}
```

Comment: here are some documentation from ms [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb268221(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Try [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx) instead.

Comment: Hi Ansgar, thanks for answer but I can't use anything else except IE com object. I have some complex Login logic(adfs, JavaScript redirect..) and I can only open site using IE.